# Safe update error with stored procedures mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I'm trying to update a table with this code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `refresh_stock`(id_product int)
BEGIN

update stock s inner join replacement r on r.product = s.product 
set s.quantity = if (s.quantity = 0, r.quantity, s.quantity+r.quantity), s.refresh_date = now()
where s.product = id_product and r.product=id_product and r.date_replacement > s.refresh_date;
END
```

Basically, I have to update a number of items in a stock every time.I buy new products. The thing is, this procedure worked two times, then it stopped working and it's giving me this error: **Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.**

I tried to pass in the parameter the stock id, but it gives me the same error above. How can I solve this problem **WITHOUT** disable safe update?

Comment: This may be irrelevant but what is `e.quantity` I see now alias `e` for any table?

Comment: So i am guesssing this error is coming from a tool like MYSQL Workbench or something similiar right?

Comment: Yes, I'm using mysql workbench. And I'm sorry, it's because my code is in portuguese and I tried to translate do english to make more sense for you guys. 'e.quantity' is the same as 's.quantity'.

Comment: Then do as it says, you can change that option in WorkBench

Comment: Open a tab on your database -> Edit -> Preferences->SQL Editor and uncheck the checkbox saying "Safe Updates"Forbid........

Comment: I know I can do it, but I wanna know why am I getting this error even with the where clause....

Comment: Yet In 2017 I get the same error even with WHERE clause. What I do inside a procedure when I know an update is safe is set sql_safe_updates = 0; before my update and then set sql_safe_updates = 1; after it